# Problem with 'specify' field in jQuery, not returning to the default value

Tags: jquery, django

I'm having a problem with the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#list').change(function(){
    $('#specify')[$(this).val()=='Other' ? 'show' : 'hide']();
  });
});
```

/// id 'list' is the id of the choice field form and id 'specify' is the id of the field that appears when 'Other' is selected, that is '0' by default.

I'm creating an app with Django that has a choice field with some of the popular selections. But I wanted that if the choice 'Other' is selected another field appears. I managed to do it, and it's working but with the following 'bug': if 'Other' is selected, and you type an input and then change again to one of the items in the list, the input is still there. How can I use jQuery in order to write a '0' if it goes from 'Other' to one of the other choices of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanted that if the choice 'Other' is selected another field appears.

So when `$('#list')` value is `Other`, `$('#specify')` should show... And hide for any other value.

Try using [.toggle(display)](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) were a `.toggle(true)` is the same has `.show()` and `.toggle(false)` is the same has `.hide()`

Below, the true/false is made by the `$(this).val()!=='Other'` condition.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#list').change(function(){
    $('#specify').val(0).toggle($(this).val()!=='Other');
  });
});
```

Comment: yeah, that's working, too, and probably in a better way. But the problem is still there, I want the object of the 'specify' field to reset to '0' if the user change again to other item of the list (i need this because of some validations I made). In the current way if you change to other item, the field hides, but with the user input. So if the user input is not validated, you are geting the error even if other item in the list is selected (because the input is still there, just hidden)